# Delete files from directory while iterating through it using NSDirectoryEnumerator

Tags: iphone, objective-c

If I for example do this:

```
NSDirectoryEnumerator *directoryEnumerator = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtURL:cacheDirectory
                                                                  includingPropertiesForKeys:@[NSURLContentAccessDateKey]
                                                                                     options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles
                                                                                errorHandler:nil];

NSURL *fileURL;
while (fileURL = [directoryEnumerator nextObject])
{
    NSDate *fileDate;
    [fileURL getResourceValue:&fileDate forKey:NSURLContentAccessDateKey error:nil];

    if ([cacheDate compare:fileDate] == NSOrderedDescending) // Delete all files with access date older then cacheDate(defined elsewhere)
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:fileURL error:nil];
}
```

Can the directory enumerator get "corrupted", for example can I get unexpected results, because index of each file changes?

I would however like to use the `enumeratorAtURL` method and not `contentsOfDirectoryAtURL` because I have to deal with large amount of files (more then 100,000). So `contentsOfDirectoryAtURL` takes a lot of memory.

Comment: Is the objective here to remove all the files? If it is you may want to consider storing them in a subdirectory of `NSDocumentDirectory`, that way when you want to remove all the files, you can just delete the folder.

Comment: Nope, I want to delete only files older then specified date. So that I keep the total size of files under certain amount. It's a custom cache directory for items downloaded from web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea to remove items from a container while iterating through it.

You could save all `fileURL`s that you want to delete in an array and then iterate through the array to delete the files.

Something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *urlsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSDirectoryEnumerator *directoryEnumerator = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtURL:cacheDirectory
                                                                  includingPropertiesForKeys:@[NSURLContentAccessDateKey]
                                                                                     options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles
                                                                                errorHandler:nil];

NSURL *fileURL;
while (fileURL = [directoryEnumerator nextObject])
{
    NSDate *fileDate;
    [fileURL getResourceValue:&fileDate forKey:NSURLContentAccessDateKey error:nil];

    if ([cacheDate compare:fileDate] == NSOrderedDescending) // Delete all files with access date older then cacheDate(defined elsewhere)
        [urlsToDelete addObject:fileURL];
}

for (NSURL *fileURL in urlsToDelete) {
     [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:fileURL error:nil];
}
```

Comment: Hmm thats exactly what I would get if I would use contentsOfDirectoryAtURL like: `NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:cacheDirectory includingPropertiesForKeys:@[NSURLContentAccessDateKey] options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles error:nil];` Which in my testing with 200,000 files uses up to 170 MB of RAM. and thats something I would like to avoid....

Comment: I don't think so. My code only stores `NSURL`s and not whole files and  further it doesn't store all urls but only those to be deleted. Am I wrong?

Comment: Basically what I would like to know is NSDirectoryEnumerator still generating some internal list of files in memory or is it constantly looking into the file system for each iteration. I did some tests and it seems it is generating an internal list. But I would like to be sure before I use it in a real app.

Comment: Sorry, i commented and did not see your comment... Yes it only stores NSURL objects... but that can still be huge if you have 200,000 files ... As it shows in my tests 170 MB ... even if I use an enumerator it still takes around 80 MB which is why I believe it uses some internal list

Comment: Okay. But now you have a different question that is "Does NSDirectoryEnumerator use an internal list?". In your starting post you asked "Can the directory enumerator get corrupted?" and the answer is "yes, it can" and I provided a safe alternative. I suggest you start another thread for your second question because now it is getting confusing.

Comment: I just now see your code(the post was without code)... I believe I'm going to implement it like that just to be safe

Comment: What if another process or app like the finder deletes a file while iterating through the folder?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this Apple documentation on Enumeration](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Enumerators.html):

> It is not safe to remove, replace, or add to a mutable collection’s elements while enumerating through it. If you need to modify a collection during enumeration, you can either make a copy of the collection and enumerate using the copy or collect the information you require during the enumeration and apply the changes afterwards.

You might want to save the files you want to delete in another array and perform the deletions afterwards.